# htaccess redirect specific files and folders to new a site AND anything else to a specific page on the new site

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting

I can't find anyone asking or the answer to my specific scenario.

I am moving an old e-Commerce site with a ton of static product and info pages to a new e-Commerce software package installed in a new location (into a new folder in the root). 
http://domain.com into http://domain.com/newstore

I know I can redirect the whole site to the new location but that won't work since much of the new site runs dynamically from the eCommerce software and the product page addresses aren't even close to the old ones.

I have created individual rewrites using RedirectMatch for all the product pages I know need to be redirected so that is good. Now I need any pages I may have missed to redirect to the new store's home page but I obviously can't redirect what I don't know. So there's my issue, how do I now get any left over pages redirected to the home page without ruining the 200 some RedirectMatch rules I have in place?

Comment: Can you show what you have? That'll probably make answering easier

Comment: Sorry, due to my rep so far I can't post any extra links :( @JonLin appears to be on the right track though.

Comment: You could edit the .htaccess file into the question (if it's still necessary.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `RedirectMatch` is mod_alias, not mod_rewrite. The two modules don't always play nicely with each other when directives from both get applied to the same URI. Without any idea how your site is setup, there's no way to answer your question, but you can try something like this using *mod_rewrite*:

```
RewriteEngine On
# Check that the request isn't for an existing resource
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# Check that the request isn't for the new store
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/newstore
# redirect to the new store
RewriteRule ^ /newstore/ [L,R]
```

The reasoning here is that if a request isn't for an existing page, image, script, something that would possibly result in a 404, and if the request isn't for the dynamic site that is in the `/newstore` folder, then we redirect it to the `/newstore/` folder.

But like I said, you've got 200 something `RedirectMatch` directives and mod_alias doesn't always play nice with mod_rewrite. You *may* need to translate them all into rewrite rules, but it's probably not necessary. Example:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/old-path/old-page.html$ /newstore/?page=123
```

would translate to:

```
RewriteRule ^/old-path/old-page.html$ /newstore/?page=123 [L,QSA,R=301]
```

All of these rewrite rules **must be *before* the rule above that redirects all 404's to /newstore*. Because it's a "catch-all" rule that is like a last resort, it needs to be after all of your regular redirects.

Comment: If I'm my understanding is correct, that will redirect anything not found - which is fine - but I also need any other pages I have not already redirected.

Comment: @LorenMcDonald if you go to those other pages that you have not already redirected, do you get a 404?

Comment: I don't know because I don't know what pages aren't there... No. Some are static pages that look like the old site and we're not worried about keeping but I don't know what may be there. I could just remove the old site contents entirely but that isn't what I wanted - Any other pages not already redirected if they exist or not should be redirected to the new home page.

Comment: To add: I guess it would be more appropriate for non-existent pages that are not already redirected go to a custom 404 page. What's left: any attempt to access any page that still exists in the old site should redirect to the new home page if it is not already redirected elsewhere.

Comment: I gave you credit for answering the question even though it forces me to remove the old store in order to correctly implement it - but that would end up being done at some point anyhow.